# Public calendar/schedule

Tags: android, ios, calendar, scheduling

The goal I am trying to achieve. I would like to create public calendar/scheduler/etc for fitness club. There are a lot of different lessons that this fitness club has, for example:

Monday:

- 10:00-11:00 Fitness Fly
- 11:00-12:00 Boxing
- 12:00-13:00 Zumba
- 13:00-14:00 Yoga

Tuesday:

- 10:00-11:00 Pilates

... and so on

So, I would like to have ability to share this data for the mobile users (android, ios) to be able to add this calendar very easy (by single click, by downloading some soft + single click or something like that. This is very important that adding this data to your mobile is supposed to be very easy process).

Other features that are really nice to have:

- Subscribe for specific lesson (for example "Yoga" only)
- Alerts/reminders about today's lessons

Comment: Good question. I have been looking at the same issue using a Google Calendar set to public, but getting people to use that *easily* across all platforms still isn't simple.

Comment: yeah, I've tried Google Calendar, but I needed to enter login and password manually what is not very good for not technical people

Comment: I use google calendars all the time, and the users I have don't need to enter a username/password other than their own into their device.  I goto the calendar and click share, and type in their emails.  Click done with the send notification box checked, and the calendars are shared.  The users goes to their phone, android users already logged in, and their is the calendar under **other calendars**.  iPhone users can add their google account, and your calendar will automatically be an option.  Users can show/hide your calendar at will.

Comment: The problem here is that you specify emails to share your calendar with. I ask for the solution where the user is adding the calendar without my help at all.

Comment: Create a google calendar.  Goto that calendars details tab.  Email a link with Embedded calendar.  **Calendar address** or **Private address** may also be useful to you.  Email clients a calendar address or private address.  How about those options?

Comment: I would like customers to suscribe to the calendar automatically. Without emails